# Shuffled Array Audio Always Starts with 0?

Tags: javascript, arrays, shuffle

I am trying to make a kind of music where tracks are chosen at random, one coming directly after another (and eventually fading together so that one track overlaps with the next, making for morphing aleatoric music, perhaps eventually somewhat self-composing, etc.)

I am "randomizing" the tracks by putting the audio files in an array and then shuffling the array. However, every time I load the page, though the array is shuffled, the first selection in the array is always #1. In other words, if my array is [1,3,4,7,9] and I run the script three times, tracks will play [1,3,7,4,9], then [1,4,7,9,3], then [1,3,9,7,4], where the first track is always 1. I would like the first track to be random as well. Any suggestions?

```
var audio = new Audio(),
i = 0;
var playlist = new Array('TRACKS/1.ogg', 'TRACKS/2.ogg', 'TRACKS/3.ogg', 'TRACKS/4.ogg', 'TRACKS/5.ogg', 'TRACKS/6.ogg', 'TRACKS/7.ogg', 'TRACKS/8.ogg', 'TRACKS/9.ogg');

audio.addEventListener('timeupdate', function(){
            var buffer = .8
            if(this.currentTime > this.duration - buffer){
                i = ++i < playlist.length ? i : 0;
console.log(i)
audio.src = playlist[i];
readFiles()
            }}, false);

audio.volume = 0.3;
audio.loop = false;
audio.src = playlist[0];

function shuffle(array) {
var currentIndex = array.length, temporaryValue, randomIndex;

// While there remain elements to shuffle...
while (0 !== currentIndex) {

// Pick a remaining element...
randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
currentIndex -= 1;

// And swap it with the current element.
temporaryValue = array[currentIndex];
array[currentIndex] = array[randomIndex];
array[randomIndex] = temporaryValue;
}

return array;
}

function readFiles(){        
playlist = shuffle(playlist);
for(var i = 0; i < playlist.length; ++i){
audio.play();
}
readFiles(); //to read undefinitly
}

readFiles();
```

Comment: Remove this:`audio.src = playlist[0];`

Comment: No audio plays whatsoever in that case.

Comment: Then add audio.src = playlist[0]; inside readFiles() function after shuffle

Comment: @Tom my bad, I was focused on the random process on why it always started at first position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I only needed to call shuffle(playlist) before the readFiles() function. Easy... Thanks.